# IOS Append Post Request

Tags: ios, forms, post

I want to input something like:

```
address[address1] = adsads
address[address2] = dsadsad
address[address3] = vadsa
```

I know if it's simple post, I can do:

```
url?address1=adsads&address2=dsadsa
```

but if I want to make it an address object(array) in the post, how shall I make it in IOS?

Comment: Friend, this is your 20th question.. Please learn how to format your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you could use a dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary * argDict = [NSMutableDictinary new];
[argDict setObject:@"John" forKey:@"name"];
[argDict setObject:@"26" forKey:@"age"];
...
NSMutableString * url = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:30];
[url appendString:@"http://?"];
BOOL isFirstArg = YES;
for (NSString * key in [argDict allKeys]) {
    if (isFirstArg) {
        [url appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [argDict objectForKey:key]];
        isFirstArg = NO;
        continue;
    }
    [url appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, [argDict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Note : I guess you could also find a better way to handle the first arg :)

Answer (score 0):

Thought of using a dictionary(might be working if I do), but just get told I can just pass url like:

```
url?address[addres1]=dsadsa&address[address2]=dsadsa
```

because browser and server won't auto encode it and reading [] as special characters.

stupid question, thank you for all the answers

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that address1,address2,address3, ... etc are integers, you can do it using switch as per below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < addressX; i++)
{
     switch(i)
     {
         case address1:
              address[i]=adsads;
              break;
         case address2:
              address[i]=aoao;
              break;
         case address3:
              address[i]=olol;
              break;
         case address4:
              address[i]=dodo;
              break;
         case address5:
              address[i]=lolo;
              break;
     }
}
```